# How to do pattern matching query in node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am trying to execute a simple query with pattern matching using `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause using [node-oracledb NodeJS library](http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#select), however I can't seem to figure out how to do it. This doesn't seem to work

```
const baseQuery = 
 `select item, item_desc
    from item_master
   where item_level=tran_level
     and item like '%:item%'`;

const binds = { item: '550' };
const result = await conn.execute(baseQuery, binds, {});
```

It keeps throwing the error below-

```
[Error: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number] {
  errorNum: 1036,
  offset: 0
}
```

I've read the node-oracledb documentation but this seemingly simple use case of pattern match queries doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Is pattern matching supported? if yes, then what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered in your cross post at https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1195

Use a normal bind variable in the SQL statement (which is important for scalability and security, so that data is never treated as part of the SQL statement).  Then concatenate whatever pattern matching syntax you want to the data.

To quote sla100's answer in the GitHub issue:

> SQL:
>
> `and item like :item`
>
> JS:
>
> `const binds = { item: '%550%' };`

You can do this with LIKE comparisons and also REGEXP_LIKE.  The node-oracledb documentation also has examples of doing this in [`WHERE IN`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein).

Comment: Just curious as to why this `and item like '%:item%'` with binds doesn't work but `and item like '%1234%'` works?

Comment: Because of the separation between SQL text and data text.  A colon in quotes is just a colon in data, and doesn't get parsed as a bind variable.

Comment: so the colon in quotes is a problem if we take this out of the equation like `and item like %:item%` and `const binds = { item: '550' };` doesn't seem to work, is the quote being included in the SQL query text internally?

Comment: Quotes are not included; they delineate the JS string. node-oracledb binds this string to the `:item` in the SQL statement.  The key thing is that your data needs to have the `%`, not the SQL statement text.